# How to control the displayed order of the Intent windows?

Tags: android

I hope my app display intent0 window first, after I click OK or Cancel in intent0 window, then the intent1 will be displayed.

But in fact, the intent1 displayed first, then intent0 displayed.

How can I do? thanks!

```
    if (MonitorWiFi_Helper.IsEnableAdmin(getApplicationContext())==false){
        ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyAdmin.class);                 
    Intent intent0 = new Intent(    DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent0.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, compName);
    intent0.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Additional text explaining why this needs to be added.");
    startActivityForResult(intent0, RESULT_ENABLE); 
    }


   if (PublicParFun.IsFirstRun(getApplicationContext())){
      Intent intent1 = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),ui.UnlockAddWiFi.class);
      startActivityForResult(intent1, RESULT_ADDWIFI);          
   }
```

Comment: If you start your first intent, run your second one in onActivityResult.

Comment: Thanks! I think your way is good, but is there other way?

Comment: Why do you need a different way? What falmnasrri said is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I think this way is little complex if I have more Intents. In other language, there are modal window concept, it will be more easier if it can use modal window